# How to write a reader macro to transfer the code in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp

I want to write a macro named `$=>` to transfer the code like:

```
(let [bb 11] ($=> @"aa#{bb}"))    => ["aa?" 11]
```

which means that I want to splite all string after `@` with the pattern `#\{.*?\}`
and replace the pattern with `?` and then eval the symbal of the patten.

So I write the macro like this:

```
(defmacro parser [clause]
   (if (and (sequential? clause)
            (= 2 (count clause))
            (= `deref (first clause))
            (string? (second clause)))
    (let [s (second clause)
          regx#  #"#\{(.*?)\}"
          m# (re-matcher regx# s)
          p# (take-while #(not (nil? %)) (repeatedly #(second (re-find m#))))
          ss# (clojure.string/replace s #"#\{(.*?)\}" "?" )
          ps# (map symbol p#)]
      `[~ss# ~@ps#])
   clause))
```

This macro works well

```
user=> (let [aa 11] (parser @"AAA#{aa}" ))
["AAA?" 11]

user=> (let [aa 11] (parser @"AA{aa}" ))
["AA{aa}"]
```

But I want the macro `$=>` can transfer all of the pattern in the code , like:

```
(let [a 1 b 2 c 3] 
     ($=> @"AAA#{a}" 
          (if true @"BBB#{b}") 
          (for [i (range 1)] @"CCC#{c}")))
```

and it can return

```
[["AAA?" 1] ["BBB?" 2] (["CCC?" 3])]
```

I have tried some method and all of them failed.

Now I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: clojure doesn't support custom reader macros, but you can do what you want with a suitably named macro and a varags ``[ & clauses]`` I believe.

Comment: IMHO, for idiomatic clojure, tagged literals are a better option for this use case, something like #interpol "string {aa}" or #is "string {aa}" and let the "@" to mean always deref, after all that's what you are comparing against, in the parser macro. The reader function for #interpol or #is could return a function that take a map as an argument